# Use Code Tunnel in VS Code to connect to website reachable from remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vpn

I have a remote computer that connects to a server via VPN.
I'm able to mount the server's share onto my remote and access it via Code Tunnel in VS Code.

This works quite good, but what I'm missing is access to a website that only reachable for the remote computer via the VPN. Is there anyway that I can do some port forward in VS Code so that my client can reach the website via the remote's VPN connection?